# How can I make -e catch an error in a script within a script?

Tags: bash

Lets say I have `apple.sh`

```
set -e
...some commands #X...
./banana.sh
...more commands #Y..
```

and then `banana.sh`

```
set -e
...some commands #Z...
```

My expectation was that if an error was thrown somewhere in `banana.sh`, that this would quit `banana.sh` in an error state, and therefore `apple.sh` would also see the error and quit.  I feel like I've even seen that be the behavior.  But now I am seeing that this is not true, and while `banana.sh` quits as expected when an error occurs, `apple.sh` barges on from there continuing on with the "some commands #Y" stuff.

How can I make the error in `banana` bubble up and be caught by `apple`?

This is on RHEL5

Comment: This should have happened just exactly according to your expectation. If `./banada.sh` exits with an error than `apple.sh` exits too. You should debug this by inserting `echo $?` just after the invocation of `./banada.sh` in `apple.sh` so see if the banada is really failing.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be your case, but did you call `banana.sh` in a specific context where `-e` is being ignored?

In [the Bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) you can read a detailed explanation about such a context, with the important info as follows:

> If a compound command or shell function executes in a context where -e is being ignored, none of the commands executed within the compound command or function body will be affected by the -e setting, even if -e is set and a command returns a failure status. If a compound command or shell function sets -e while executing in a context where -e is ignored, that setting will not have any effect until the compound command or the command containing the function call completes.

This means if you have the following `apple.sh`:

```
set -e

func() {
        echo '...some commands #X...'
        false # Suppose ./banana.sh fails here
        echo '...some commands #Y...'
        true
}

if func; then
        echo 'func() returns success'
else
        echo 'func() returns failure'
fi
```

You'll get the following output:

```
...some commands #X...
...some commands #Y...
func() returns success
```

Not only bash, but other shells including dash and zsh will give the same result.

To answer your question, there's apparently no way to change the behavior at least on bash.